# $\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)(2x^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $x = \sin(t)$
which implies
$dx = \cos(t)dt,$

$1 - x^2 = 1 - \sin^2(t) = \cos^2(t), 2x^2 - 1 = 2\sin^2(t) - 1 = \sin^2(t).$

So, our integral becomes:$ \int \frac{\cos(t)}{\cos^2(t)\sin^{1/4}(t)} dt $

Am I right?

Comment: $2\sin^2(t)-1=-\cos(2t)$.

Comment: Without trigonometric substitution is there any method to solve this?

Comment: Mathematica gives a result in terms of [this hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/)

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{2 x^2-1}}\right)-\cot
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{2 x^2-1}}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the most unplesant term
$$\sqrt[4]{2 x^2-1}=t \quad\implies\quad x=\frac{\sqrt{t^2+1}}{\sqrt{2}}\quad\implies\quad dx=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t^2+1}}$$ which make
$$I=-\sqrt 2\,\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\left(t^2-1\right) \sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt$$

Now
$$\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}=u\quad\implies\quad t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-u^4}}{u^2}\quad\implies\quad dt=-\frac{2 \left(1+\sqrt{1-u^4}\right)}{u^3 \sqrt{1-u^4}}\,du$$
$$I=\int \frac{u^2}{1-u^4}\,du=\frac 12\int \frac {du}{1-u^2}-\frac 12\int \frac {du}{1+u^2}$$
Now, this is simple.

Comment: I got   $ = \frac{1}{4} \ln|\frac{x+(2x^2-1)^{1/4}}{x-(2x^2-1)^{1/4}}| - \frac{1}{2} \arctan[\frac{(2x^2-1)^{1/4}}{x}]+C
$ am I right ?

Comment: Differentiate to see!